# Vagrant VBoxGuessAdditions error

Tags: vagrant

I created a Vagrant box with Ubuntu + KDE. I have a problem with resolution screen in this. A perhaps way to resolve this is install new VBoxGuessAdditions.

Indeed I change boolean (from false to true) on this line on my vagrantFile :

```
config.vbguest.auto_update = true
```

With this line at 'false' value I have no problem for up my vagrant. 
But when a set this config at 'true' I have this error :

```
    Installing the Window System drivers
Installing X.Org Server 1.17 modules ...done.
Setting up the Window System to use the Guest Additions ...done.
You may need to restart the the Window System (or just restart the guest system)
to enable the Guest Additions.

Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.12. Some functionality may not work as
intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
stdin: is not a tty
Cleaning up downloaded VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO...
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/Users/mynickname/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.11.0/lib/vagrant-vbguest/download.rb:23:in `unlink': P
ermission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/mynickname/.vagrant.d/tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.12.iso (Errno::EAC
CES)
        from C:/Users/mynickname/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.11.0/lib/vagrant-vbguest/download.rb:23:i
n `cleanup'
        from C:/Users/mynickname/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.11.0/lib/vagrant-vbguest/hosts/base.rb:62
:in `cleanup'
        from C:/Users/mynickname/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.11.0/lib/vagrant-vbguest/installers/base.
rb:194:in `cleanup'
```

**My environment :**

- OS Host : Windows 7 pro
- VirtualBox : 5.0.12 r104815
- Vagrant : 1.8.1
- ruby : 1.9.3p545

***Can anyone know what doing on this vagrant and information of VBoxGuessAdditions ?***

Answer (score 0):

Try Vagrant 1.7.X. I had the same issue with 1.8.X.

Cheers,